should the standardisation of numerical variables be carried out before or after the rebalancing technique of the target variable?
I am dealing with a classification task of a binary target variable (company failure prediction yes or no) for a university project. I was wondering, should the standardisation of numerical variables be carried out before or after the rebalancing technique of the target variable?

I assume that by rebalancing you’re referring to some kind of matching procedure - so it depends on how you’re carrying out the matching; some methods will be invariant, others won’t

I used the SMOTE technique

Welcome to Cross Validated! 1) Why did you run the SMOTE? Oversampling is typically a solution to a non-problem, and SMOTE does not even seem to be particularly good at synthesizing new points. 2) Why do you want to standardize? It's not a theorem that you have to standardize, even though it can make sense in some situations.

I performed the standardisation because I have x1-x15 variables (two categorical ones that I turned into dummies) whose scale and meaning I do not know.
As for SMOTE, looking at similar tasks on github and kaggle it was used to balance the minority class of the target.
I don't know if that makes sense

I performed the standardisation because I have x1-x15 variables (two categorical ones that I turned into dummies) whose scale and meaning I do not know. This does not seem like a reason to standardize. If you are doing deep learning and want your values to be in $[0, 1]$ for computational reasons, some kind of standardization could make sense. If you want to interpret your coefficients in terms of how many standard deviations the variable must change to elicit a certain change in the outcome, standardization could make sense. My answer to your question would be different for each situation.

So how does not knowing what the variables mean lead to standardization?

On top of that, the bias induced by the oversampling will probably skew your coefficients pretty severely - so not sure what standardization accomplishes w.r.t. inference since the augmentation destroys interpretability
